# What happens after JobIntentService's onDestroy is called?

Tags: android, observable, rx-java, android-jobscheduler, jobintentservice

I have a question related to lifecycle of a `JobIntentService`. From the documentation, I found out that the `JobIntentService` is destroyed right after `onHandleWork(Intent intent)` has returned. `onHandleWork` runs on background, so I can run blocking operations here. Then, what happens if I would like to run the actual execution asynchronously? I seems like everything runs as intended, but it's quite hard to understand that the Service is still running in background even after `onDestroy` is called. Below is my implementation of `onHandleWork`.

```
override fun onHandleWork(intent: Intent) {
    if (!processor.isProcessing) {
        subscription.add(processor.startProcessing()
                .subscribe({
                    // Do something
                }, { t ->
                    t.printStackTrace()
                    // Do something
                }))
    }
}
```

How does this actually run on background while the Service is actually "Destroyed"?

Answer (score 1):

The `onHandleWork` method executes your logic, if your logic starts asynchronous tasks, `JobIntentService` tells itself that the task you gave it is executed (the task you gave it is to execute an asynchronous task SIMPLY) therefore you receive `onDestroy()` immediately

If `onHandleWork` directly executes your logic (which includes a long process) then `onDestroy()` will be called as soon as your process is finished

To fully understand the difference, you need to know that the `onHandleWork` method SIMPLY execute your logic.

Example:

1 - `onHandleWork`-> `Asynctask.execute()` -> `onDestroy()`

2 - `onHandleWork`-> for loop -> `onDestroy()`

On (1-) you tell the `onHandleWork` method to execute an Asynchronous task, but not to continue to follow the progress of the process, `onHandlework` executes `.execute()` (it takes only a few milliseconds)

On (2-) you tell the `onHandleWork` method to execute a loop, which blocks the called of `onDestroy()` until your loop ends.